# Why Hibernate creates new database connection every request?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have Java - Spring Boot - Hibernate - Postgres application. And hibernate creates database connection every request, why? Is there configurable? For example, for one session to last 10 minutes?

My Hibernate configuration:

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "monitoring" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "false");
    properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation", "true");
    return properties;
}
```

And every request I'm getting following log:

`11:19:13.584 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/monit]`

Why? How can I change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure connection pools manually since you define a DataSource.
From [Spring official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connect-to-production-database) :

> If you define your own DataSource bean, auto-configuration does not occur.

Starting from spring boot 2, `HikariCP` is the default Connection Pool embedded with spring boot starter (`spring-boot-starter-jdbc` and `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`).

You can configure the maximum pool size with the following configuration with `HikariCP`

```
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size= 10
```